# Delete Stored Procedure not working in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure for deleting a record in my table.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE BIRD_STRIKE_INCIDENT_DELETE  @row text
AS 
BEGIN
    DELETE FORM bird_strike.incidents WHERE row_names = @row
END
 delimiter ; 
 
 Call BIRD_STRIKE_INCIDENT_DELETE('11')
```

Can someone provide pointers on what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: `FORM` should be `FROM`

Comment: Oops, good catch! But that didnt work either :/

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add what error you're experiencing or what output you're getting. Also, fix that typo if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: You are missing `//` after your `END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider this approach.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.procedures 
          WHERE Name = 'BIRD_STRIKE_INCIDENT_DELETE')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.BIRD_STRIKE_INCIDENT_DELETE;
END;
else
BEGIN
      CREATE PROCEDURE BIRD_STRIKE_INCIDENT_DELETE  (_row text)
      BEGIN
         DELETE FROM bird_strike.incidents WHERE row_names = _row;
      END
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks more like SQL Server than MySql

This should be so

```
Delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE BIRD_STRIKE_INCIDENT_DELETE  (_row text)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM bird_strike.incidents WHERE row_names = _row;
END//
delimiter ;
```